# Unity, how to have multiple 2D collider on single object

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I have a tower defense game. I want to modify the walk animation of ennemies, so that depending of their position on the map, i can use front, left, right walk animations.

I want to use 2D colliders, so that when an ennemies enter inside the new zone, i can detect with TriggerEnter and change the animation of the Walk.

Which kind of collider should i use to achieve this ? I mean, Which collider should I use to have different colliders side by side like in the image ?

Thanks.

[image]

Update:
In this example you can see ennemies moving following a path and in this situation, i should detect the position to have another animation, for example profile walk.
[image]

Comment: I think this is a bad solution, and a tedious one to make in game. To make enemies move, you move them in a direction, just apply an animation based on direction instead.

Comment: @GuillemVS, but it is a 2D game, all assets are in 2D. How could I know the direction ? The ennemies are moving following a path

Comment: Even as simply as setting the animation based on velocity. Unity allows you to make animations which merely change the sprite, and you can specify which animation via the direction of the characters through the animator. Look it up.

Comment: @GuillemVS i know, what do you don't get is the fact that i need to know the right moment to change the animation. It is not chaging the animation the issue. When should I change is. That's why i was thinking about adding colliders to detect if ennemy is in a zone of walk i should change the walk animation

Comment: If I am interpreting this correctly, you want to change the animation based on the "direction" and not necessarily on the "position".  You could capture the position (Vector2) during the Update (or FixedUpdate) and then over the course of a few frames determine the "direction" the unit is heading and change the animation based the "direction".  This will be much more flexible and will happen automagically once it is in place.  You may have to fiddle with how many frames to capture and the transition directions.

Comment: I'm making a similar 2D game where the user clicks on the screen and the player will go in the clicked position so I have to do a few checks to determine the sprite face (left or right). The way I'm handling it is how @Topher suggests. Basically in the Update method I'm checking the player's X-Axis, I compare the previous X position with the current one, if the current X is more than the previous that means my character walks on the right direction otherwise is going to the left direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used this solution. Thank you all

```
            Vector2 currentDirection = (points.ways[wayIndex].wayPoints[wayPointIndex].position - transform.position).normalized;
        if (Mathf.Abs(currentDirection.x) >= Mathf.Abs(currentDirection.y))
        {
            //Character is moving sideways
            if (currentDirection.x > 0)
            {
                print("Move Rigth");
            }
            else
            {
                print("Move Left");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Character is moving straight

            if (currentDirection.y > 0)
            {
                print("Move Up");

            }
            else
            {
                print("Move Down");

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to achieve the face direction.

1. **First Method**

You can compare the current X-Axis with the next one and simply flip your sprite on the X-Axis.

```
private float _currentPosOnXAxis;
public SpriteRenderer _spriteRenderer;

private void Update()
{
    FaceDirection();
}

private void FaceDirection()
{
    if(transform.position.x <= _currentPosOnXAxis)
    {
        _spriteRenderer.flipX = true;
    }
    else
    {
        _spriteRenderer.flipX = false;
    }

    _currentPosOnXAxis = transform.position.x;
}
```

2. **Second Method**

The second method is similar to what you have already tried. Basically you use multiple checkpoints objects not as triggers but as position points. You have a list of points on the world that each enemy should follow in a specific order and you check the enemy's X position with the next checkpoint X position.

So what you check is that if the enemy's X position is bigger than the checkpoint X position, that means the enemy is on the right side of the checkpoint so the enemy is moving to the left, but if the enemy's X position is less than the checkpoint X position, that means the enemy is on the left side and is moving to the right.

You can use a list of all the checkpoints and you start from 0 index and you can use a trigger to determine that the enemy has pass through the checkpoint and increase the index number.

```
public SpriteRenderer _spriteRenderer;
public List<Transform> _checkpointsTransforms;
private int _currentIndex = 0;
private float _checkpointXPosition = _checkpointsTransforms[_currentIndex];


private void Update()
{
    if(transform.position.x > _checkpointXPosition)
    {
        _spriteRenderer.flip = true;
    }
    else
    {
        _spriteRenderer.flip = false;
    }
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if(col.CompareTag("CheckPoint"))
    {
       _currentIndex++;
       if(currentIndex < _checkpointsTransforms.Count)
       {
           _checkpointXPosition = _checkpointsTransforms[_currentIndex];
       }
    }
}
```

**Note:** Remember to set your `Tag` accordingly

I would recommend the first method because is much more faster and it requires less memory. Also the second method it means that for each map you need to create all the checkpoints that you need and all the enemies should have a reference to those checkpoints and so on.